# XML Serialize a Pushpin for Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, serialization, isolatedstorage, pushpin

I'm studying Isolated Storage and have successfully stored objects in it, now I'm trying to store a Pushpin in isolated storage. I straight up copied the method I used to serialize an object and store it.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = IsolatedStorageFile
    .GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile("home.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Pushpin>));
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, p);
    }
}
```

Where `p` is a pushpin, the error it's throwing is

> There was an error reflecting type Pushpin.

I could cheaply create a class to store Lat/Long, store that and recreate the pushpins, but I'd like to understand/figure out why I can't serialize this object.

My end goal is to permanently store a list of pushpins so users can track journeys they've been on - just something to help me learn Bing maps and Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The Pushpin class is not designed to be serializable and thus the issue you are getting. The best option is to create an object that stores the information for the pushpin and to regenerate the pushpins from this data. If you are using MVVM then store your view model for the pushpin.